# insert element in specific position, keep event listeners with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert element in specific position (e.g. after a certain div. Is there a way keep event listeners?

E.g. in example I want to insert after 2nd one:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div id="insert_after_this"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

As far as I understand only `appendChild` keeps listeners, but I'm not sure how to use it to insert to certain position.

Comment: Well how are you trying to do it now?

Comment: anything that doesn't convert the element into html and back again should work?

Comment: Have you looked into something like [insertAdjacentElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement)?

Comment: Seems like insertBefore/After keeps listeners